# convert a method to propositional statement

Tags: java, boolean, discrete-mathematics

I have homework that gives a Boolean functions and asked to write it in  a simple logical propositional statement.
I don't get the main idea how to convert it to propositional.
Is return means implies? and else is or? and nested if means and?

1

```
boolean m_1(p, q, r){
if (p || q)
return (!r)
else
return False}
```

2

```
    boolean m_10(p, q, r){
if (p)
if (r)
return False
else
return True
else if (!r)
return (q)}
```

I solved the first one like this:

pVq→¬rVF

but I get confused with the second

my answer is

(pΛq→F)V(pΛ¬r→TVq)

Do I understand it correctly?

Comment: This isn't Java code, so why did you tag it as such?

Comment: 1) Indent your code for human readability. 2) Java keywords are in all lowercase, i.e. `false` and `true`. 3) The parameters of a Java method must be typed, e.g. `boolean p`.

Comment: Even if you did fix the code, the second example doesn't make any sense. Supposed `!p` and `!!r` (`r`), what then?

Comment: it's discrete  math homework, I thought its java code coz it's the nearest  language I think

Answer (score 0):

I think you're right on the first one.

The second one is something like this:
(pΛq→F)V(pΛ¬r→T)V(¬pΛ¬r -> q)

Unfortunately I'm no expert on formally noting these.
It is easier to see like this:

`boolean m_10(p, q, r){
if (p)
   if (r)
     return False
   else
     return True
else if (!r)
    return (q)
}`

Answer (score 0):

By using your symbols and if the 1st example is correct, then the 2nd could be written like this:

```
(p→¬r)V(¬pΛ¬r→q)
```